# Ubuntu 18.04: Brother laser HL-L2390DW on USB can't print

Tags: printing, brother, cups-lpd

I recently "upgraded" Kubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 and now I can't print anything on my Brother laser HL-L2390DW on USB.

The printer shows up in the System Settings Printers page.
Trying to print results, the printer wakes up and is showing `Receiving Data` for a few seconds, but then it goes back to Idle without actually printing anything.

The job shows up in the print queue, but remains with status `Sending Data` indefinitely. After some research I have tried removing and reinstalling the printer from System Settings, removing and reinstalling CUPS, and also running Brother's `linux-bprinter-installer` script in a terminal, all with no change.

The scanner function of the machine works fine, and I can print the printer's self-test page from its front panel. It almost seems that the system is able to perform a handshake, but can't transfer any data.  Printing to a PDF file also works fine, so it seems that only the hardware printer is affected.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: I had a similar problem with another Brother HLL Laser printer and the problem was an erroneous `CUPS` installation. Reinstalling `CUPS` did the trick. (The problem was between 18.04 and 18.04.1).